# Is it possible to create a new data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a new data type in JavaScript, like string?

Example: I have the variable *person* and I want to declare that the type of that variable is Person.

Like this:

```
var person = "idk"
console.log(typeof person)
```

Output: "Person"

Comment: You can define a class. `typeof` is for "pure" javascript types.

Comment: Yes, it is sort of possible with classes, although `typeof` will return `object` for any class you make. I get the feeling that if this is in an attempt to solve a problem, there may be a better solution. You're welcome to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63078532/edit) your post and clarify so we can give better answers.

Comment: Actually, you can in fact define a custom type, it just so happens typeof is a bit, well broken... Use `instanceof` or implement a custom .toString method instead

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The closest you can get to what you're describing is testing instanceof, or using instanceof to create your own type checking function:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name; 
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const bill = new Person("Bill", 40);

function checkType(data){
  if(data instanceof Person) return "Person";
  return typeof data; 
}

console.log(bill instanceof Person);
console.log(checkType(bill));
console.log(checkType("bill"));
```

Answer (score 16):

There are only a few return values of `typeof` as listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
Undefined         "undefined"
Null              "object" (see below)
Boolean           "boolean"
Number            "number"
BigInt            (new in ECMAScript 2020)    "bigint"
String            "string"
Symbol            (new in ECMAScript 2015)    "symbol"
Function object   (implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 terms)    "function"
Any other object  "object"
```

So as per your question, you can't have your own value for `typeof` operator. And if you create your own object with `class` or `function()` its type will be an `object`.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I would point out, that the answer to "Can I create custom types?", is a definite yes. You can not however invite `typeof` to the party.

Here are some workarounds and alternatives to using `typeof`.

#### `typeof` is broken?

The typeof operator, could be considered to be a bit broken... so won't really work for "custom" types... Actually, it does not really work as you might expect with JavaScript *primitives*.

`typeof null // "object" ?! ok...`, while there are reasons why this happens, [it's not intuitive](https://javascriptwtf.com/).

The ideal and "safe" way to check for custom types is by defining and calling a custom toString *method* on your custom object.

You can read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString_to_detect_object_class)

#### `instanceof` to the rescue

Instead of using typeof, you could consider using `instanceof`. As that will work with your "custom" class right off the bat, without needing to do any additional anything further such as implementing your own .toString method.

Here is a simple playground, demonstrating the basic idea...

```js
class Person {}

p = new Person // An instance of Person

console.log(typeof p) // Object :(
console.log(p instanceof Person) // ture :P

// And with custom .toString method
Person.prototype.toString = function(){ return 'person' }

console.log(p.toString())        // 'person'
console.log(String(p))           // 'person'
console.log(p+"")                // 'person' <-- This is a simple coercive to string expression, employing our custom .toString method.
console.log(`${p}`)              // 'person' <-- using template literals
console.log([]+p)                // 'person' <-- coercion magic ... :p
console.log(""+{}+[":"]+p)       // "[object Object]:person"
console.log((typeof {})+' '+[p]) // "object person"

// BONUS ROUND --- we can even do "custom" JSON stringifications
Person.prototype.toJSON = function (){ return { typeof: '[object Person]'} }

console.log(JSON.stringify(p)) // "{"typeof":"[object Person]"}"

// Which works, as expected...
let agent = { agent: p }
console.log(JSON.stringify(agent)) // {"agent":{"typeof":"[object Person]"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're looking for TypeScript! TypeScript is a language that compiles to JavaScript.

Here's an example from the documentation for creating a person type:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

let user: Person = { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "User" };
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#interfaces

Answer (score 1):

In world of JavaScript, `type` is not same as other OOP languages.

And there is a subtle difference between ECMA and JavaScript:

In [latest ECMA](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types), there is only **eight data types**: `Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, BigInt, and Object.`

That is to say, ECMA treats `Function` as one subtype of `Object`.

In JavaScript, we almost always treat `Function` as one separate type, because `typeof (function(){})` gives us `function`. However, `typeof []` will give us `array`, so we treat `Array` as one subtype of object, same thing happens to `Set, Map, Date, ...`, these data may exist as one separate type in some OOP language, such as Python, but in JavaScript, they are all subtype of `Object`.

So, this is the real situation we face when talking about `type` in JavaScript.

But, if don't only focus on `typeof`, we have better way to create and detect **our new data type** in JavaScript.

Speak accurately, we can create our new data subtype, sub `Object` type, and we should also detect subtype of data in JavaScript in most cases.

Key thing is `Object.prototype.toString` and `symbol.toStringTag`.

Below is demo code:

```js
function Person() {
}

const person = new Person()
const getObjTag = (obj) => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1)

console.log(getObjTag(person))  // log Object


Person.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = Person.name
console.log(getObjTag(person))  // log Person

// this method is reasonable in JS, because
console.log(getObjTag([]))  // log Array
console.log(getObjTag(new Set([])))  // log Set
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom types as `class`es since ECMASCript 2015 (ES6):

```js
class Person {
  static get type() {
    return Person.prototype.constructor.name
  }
  get type() {
    return this.constructor.name
  }
  isA(clazz) {
    return this.type === clazz.type 
  }
}

const john = new Person();
if (john.isA(Person)) {
  console.log('John is a person')
}
```

then you can also define your own `typeOf()` function:

```
const typeOf = (obj) => obj.type

console.log(typeOf(person))  // Prints 'Person'
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use a class to create a custom Object.
However, in regards to custom data types, you can't really do that.

Here's a basic example:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, nationality) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._nationality = nationality;
    }

    info() {
        return `Hi ${this._name}, you're ${this._age} years old and your nationality is ${this._nationality}!`
    };
};

const person = new Person("John", 15, "British");
console.log(person.info())
console.log(typeof person)
```

You **have** to have the `constructor` function within a class; if you do not have one then JavaScript will insert an empty one.

I'm not too experienced with classes (I've just started working with them), and I'd recommend you do some further research into them - they're dead useful.

Comment: this is not entirely correct, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString_to_detect_object_class

Comment: im new to all this class stuff